# Liquibase is trying to create the databasechangelog table again

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, maven, liquibase

In my project I have scripts that create tables, make changes, and so on, now when I add a new migration in a new file in the changeLog, I get an error. In the last migration that I added, there are no errors, because if you delete all tables from the schema and run the project, then everything will work without problems. But this option is not suitable, as a rule. The error occurs precisely when adding a new migration on top of the old one.

```
[ERROR] Error setting up or running Liquibase:
[ERROR] ??????: ????????? "databasechangelog" ??? ?????????? [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE databasechangelog (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(2
55) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INTEGER NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS V
ARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255), LABELS VARCHAR(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR(10))]
```

I use spring boot, postgres in my project. What do you think might be the problem? thanks in advance.
left it in the form of a screen too, suddenly it will be more convenient for someone)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you already have those spring configurations in your property file, It will create the liquibase tables. Make sure you are not creating it manually again in other liquibase script.

```
spring.liquibase.database-change-log-lock-table = DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK

spring.liquibase.database-change-log-table = DATABASECHANGELOG
```